# My JS file doesn't work when i convert it to Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to convert my HTML page over to Wordpress but the Javascript file isn't loading correctly to allow the slideshow to function.

I get this error in the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: plusIndex is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick ((index):143)`

This is the only code within the JS file:

```
var index = 1;

function plusIndex(n){
  index = index + 1;
  showImage(index);
}

showImage(1);

function showImage(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");

  if(n > x.length) {index = 1;}
  if(n < 1) {index = x.length;}

  for(i=0; i< x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display ="none";
  }
  x[index-1].style.display ="block"
}
```

And this is the HTML it relates to:

```
<i onclick="plusIndex(-1)" id="head-btn1" class="fa fa-chevron-left head-btn"></i>
<i onclick="plusIndex(1)" id="head-btn2" class="head-btn fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
```

I've added the code into the functions.php file:

```
function add_theme_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/index.js', array(), '1.1', true);
}
```

I've also tried to add in `wp_register_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/index.js' );` above the `wp_enqueue_script();` function, with no luck.

It all works fine on HTML page though

Comment: Are you using a child theme?

Comment: this is a completely custom built theme

Comment: Is the js loading in your DOM? Are you getting any 404 errors in your developer console in the browser?

Comment: also, where is the hook you used?